how to stop linger getting enabled
I have no idea why anybody thought "linger" was a good idea but I spend all my time, when setting up systems, turning it off.
On a Raspberry pi (bookworm)  I recently had need to do:
# usermod -l oldgraeme2 graeme

But it failed as there were processes running as "graeme" despite him (me) not being logged on , sure enough, checking:
# ls /var/lib/systemd/linger

he was there. So I did:
#loginctl disable-linger graeme

...and similar for all users I found
The processes were still there , killing them did no good  , they respawned.
So, forced to do a reboot ...back up
and all the graeme processes were back. Checking
#ls /var/lib/systemd/linger

The graeme user was back!
In the end I had to remove the user entirely (with a -f [force] ) ...so several reboots and force delete of a user  just to try to do normal system admin in the face  of whatever perverted logic lies behind "linger".
So what on earth is re-enabling linger for users?
